# Compare today's results to yesterday's and plot them on a graph

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I'm trying to build a KQL query that compares today's data to data from the previous day at the same time of day.

https://aka.ms/lademo

```
let thisWeek = SigninLogs
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
    | summarize ThisWeek = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)
    | serialize row = row_number();
let lastWeek= SigninLogs
    | where TimeGenerated between((ago(1h) - totimespan(1d)) .. (now() - totimespan(1d)))
    | summarize LastWeek = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m)
    | serialize row = row_number();
thisWeek
| join // Join data from today and yesterday together
    (
    lastWeek
    )
    on row
```

There are a few challenges I am running into:

1. Since the hour timestamps won't match exactly between the days, the results won't align exactly as shown in the results below. For example, the hour:minute of 10/31/2023, **10:13:00.000 PM** won't match 10/30/2023, **10:07:00.000 PM**. Is there a way to still bucket per minute, and if timestamps do not exist, then simply use **0**?

[image]

2. If I use a time chart instead of a grid, like in the picture below, I want to make the Y axis bigger without changing the numbers on it. In simple words, I'd like a zoom effect because the chart looks very crowded right now. Also, is there a way to get rid of columns like row1 and row from the chart?

[image]

Comment: You can use `project-away` to remove columns you don't want from the result set

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

There are many ways to do this.  The version I like is [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction) which lets you check if a value exists and if not use another one.

But there has to be something there to link to in the first place.  For time base queries I've found that [`range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rangeoperator) could be useful to start off the base data.  But you have to generate this data and from there you can have the "standard" time windows.

**Question 2**

Perhaps using a large bin window than a minute could be useful?  Say 15 minutes? [`bin(TimeGenerated, 15m)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction) Or even an hour? [`bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/binfunction)

[`project-away`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/projectawayoperator) is probably what you're looking for to remove row1 or [`project`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/projectoperator) to keep the columns you want to keep.

How I might approach what I think is your use case would be the folowing:

```
range TimeWindow from startofweek(ago(7d)) to endofday(now()) step 15m
| join kind=leftouter (
SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated >= startofweek(ago(7d))
| summarize count() by TimeWindow = floor(TimeGenerated, 15m)
) on TimeWindow
| extend count_ = coalesce(count_, 0)
| extend OverallWindow = iif(TimeWindow >= startofweek(now()), 'This Week', 'Last Week')
| extend TimeWindow = iif(OverallWindow == 'Last Week', datetime_add('day', 7, TimeWindow), TimeWindow)
| project TimeWindow, count_, OverallWindow
| render timechart
```